# How to get the bibliography in citation order using chem-acs style?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am writing my thesis and I would really like to use chem-acs as the style for my bibliography. Only drawback is that I have all the citations in alphabetic order. Is there any way I can modify it to make it as I wish?

This is my script so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=chem-acs, autocite=superscript, citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mparhack,fixltx2e,relsize}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}  
\usepackage{rotating} 
\DeclareSIUnit\molar{\textsc{M}}
\captionsetup{tableposition=top,figureposition=bottom,font=small}

\bibliography{Biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\input{Frontespizio.tex}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\input{Chapters/Part1.tex}

\input{Chapters/Part2.tex}


\backmatter

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code example minimal, but compilable.

Comment: Note that this is not a MWE by any standard: it is neither minimal (it contains lots of calls to packages that have nothing to do with citations), nor is it working, as we don't have your `.bib` file, your `\input`ed files etc., it also does not contain any citations. Please see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and [this help specific for MWEs with bibliographies](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
style=chem-acs
```

instead of

```
bibstyle=chem-acs, citestyle=numeric-comp
```

The option `sorting=none` that you need to sort by citation order is set in [`chem-acs.cbx`](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-chem/blob/master/chem-acs.cbx), which you do not load if you go with `citestyle=numeric-comp`.